# Multiple rows from a condition with multiple outputs

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have two dataframes that I want to combine based on a condition.

The first dataframe `df1` is the principal that I want to preserve and has the following structure

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  id = c("id-0023","id-0023","id-0023","id-0023","id-0023","id-0023","id-0150","id-0150","id-0150","id-0181","id-0181","id-0181","id-0181"),  
  var1 = "task01",
  var2 = c(0,0,0,2,2,4,2,4,4,2,2,4,4),
  var.start = c(161,505,796,4,131,389,364,425,782,140,181,569,753),
  var.end = c(228,526,820,55,389,941,389,470,941,176,482,631,782))

print (df1)
```

The second dataframe `df2` contains the values that I need for the condition and output variable

```
df2 <- data.frame(
    var1 = "task01",
    var2 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,4,4),
    start = c(0,143,410,741,821,919,1135,0,200,269,391,481,516,646,808,946,972,1181,0,206,386,539,555,632,782),
    end = c(143,410,741,821,919,1135,1295,200,269,391,481,516,646,808,946,972,1181,1331,206,386,539,555,632,782,941),
    var.out = c(2,2,2,4,3,4,3,4,4,3,2,4,3,3,2,1,2,2,4,2,3,1,3,4,3))
    
    print (df2)
```

I used the following solution to merge the dataframes based on the desire condition, which is matching the `var.out` according to the range `var.start >= (start - 2) & var.end <= (end + 2)`

```
output <- df1 %>%
  full_join(df2, by = c("var1", "var2")) %>% # full join for all combinations between the two dataframes
  filter(var.start >= (start - 2) & var.end <= (end + 2)) %>% # keep only the rows that meet the condition
  select(id, var2, var.start, var.end, var.out) %>% # select relevant variables 
  right_join(df1, by = c("id", "var2", "var.start", "var.end")) %>% # right join with initial dataframe to get the missing rows
  arrange(id, var2) # sort by id and var2
```

This works fine, however, I get rows with empty `var.out` because their result to the condition are multiple values. So, I wanted to ask if there is a way to end with new rows that reflect the multiple `var.out`, as following:

```
desired.output <- data.frame(
  var1 = "task01",
  id = c("id-0023","id-0023","id-0023","id-0023","id-0023","id-0023","id-0023","id-0023","id-0023","id-0023","id-0023","id-0023","id-0023","id-0023","id-0150","id-0150","id-0150","id-0181","id-0181","id-0181","id-0181","id-0181","id-0181","id-0181"),
  var2 = c(0,0,0,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,2,4,4,2,2,2,2,2,4,4),
  var.start = c(161,505,796,4,131,200,269,389,206,386,539,555,632,782,364,425,782,140,181,200,269,391,569,753),
  var.end = c(228,526,820,55,200,269,389,206,386,539,555,632,782,941,389,470,941,176,200,269,391,482,631,782),
  var.out = c(2,2,4,4,4,4,3,4,2,3,1,3,4,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,3,2,3,4))
```

Thanks

Comment: Your example is reproducible (nice!) but your algorithm is unclear. The first part with the full_join and the filter is OK, but I cannot understand what you want to achieve with the right_join in order to get your expected output.

Comment: I adapted from an answer that worked for me from this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62999898/conditional-merge-or-left-join-two-dataframes-in-r I tried several solutions and this was the one that worked better. However, I am open to different solutoons that get the expected output.

Comment: I'm also having trouble understanding the desired algorithm. I think I have a working solution, but there's (at least) one row that gives me trouble. The row with `id-0181`, `var2=2`, `var.start=181`, `var.end=482` seems like it should have a split at time 481, giving a period (391 - 481) with `var.out=2` and a period (481 - 482) with `var.out = 4`. But then this second period of time is valid to take either `var.out=2` or `var.out=4`. You don't split at this time in your desired output. Can you edit and explain what the exact criteria for splitting rows is?

Comment: @DavidLukeThiessen you are right. In this case, there is no a clear solution. In the case of my desired output, I would like that the row takes the first value `var.out=2`, applying the condition of `var.end <= (end + 2)`. However, it will also be a good solution if in that case the row is double, and I get an output of two rows one with `var.out=2` and one with `var.out=4`

Comment: In your desired.output `id-0023` has something strange happening in rows 8, 9, and 10 . I couldn't figure out any logic to it, so I assumed it was a mistake and posted my solution. If the behaviour in rows 8-10 is deliberate, could you please explain the logic behind it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that we need to divide the rows in `df1` into multiple rows depending on when the value of `var.out` changes in `df2`. I don't know a nice way to do this, so I made a messy nested loop to achieve it. The basic idea is we divide `df1` into groups based on `id`, `var1`, and `var2`. Call one of these groups `dat1_idvar1var2`. Then for each row in `dat1_idvar1var2` we check if one of the corresponding `start` values in `df2` is inside that row. If it is we divide the row into two and continue checking. This is a very clumsy loop and is slower than it needs to be, but it works.

```r
# divides the first dataset into additional rows based on the 
# start times in the second dataset.
# If a start in dat2 is inside the range of (var.start, var.end)
# in dat1, split that row into two, then continue processing the
# rows in dat1.
splitdata <- function(dat1, dat2) {
  outdat <- dat1[NULL, ]
  for(i in levels(factor(dat1$id))) {
    dat1_id <- filter(dat1, id == i)
    for(j in levels(factor(dat1_id$var1))) {
      dat1_idvar1 <- filter(dat1_id, var1 == j)
      dat2_var1 <- filter(dat2, var1 == j)
      for(k in levels(factor(dat1_idvar1$var2))) {
        dat1_idvar1var2 <- filter(dat1_idvar1, var2 == k)
        dat2_var1var2 <- filter(dat2_var1, var2 == k)
        continue <- TRUE
        while(continue == TRUE) {
          work <- split_row(dat_target = dat1_idvar1var2, 
                            split_times = dat2_var1var2$start)
          if(work$did_split == TRUE) {
            dat1_idvar1var2 <- work$dat_out
          } else {
            continue <- FALSE
          }
        }
        outdat <- rbind(outdat, dat1_idvar1var2)
      }
    }
  }
  return(outdat)
}
split_row <- function(dat_target, split_times) {
  for(i in 1:nrow(dat_target)) {
    for(j in 1:length(split_times)) {
      if((dat_target$var.start[i] < split_times[j]) & 
         (dat_target$var.end[i] > split_times[j])) {
        dat_out <- dat_target[-i,]
        newrow1 <- dat_target[i,]
        newrow1[1, "var.end"] <- split_times[j]
        newrow2 <- dat_target[i,]
        newrow2[1, "var.start"] <- split_times[j]
        dat_out <- rbind(dat_out, newrow1, newrow2)
        return(list(dat_out = dat_out, did_split = TRUE))
      }
    }
  }
  return(list(dat_out = dat_target, did_split = FALSE))
}
```

After we first process `df1` by this function, then your code works (mostly).

```r
outdat <- splitdata(dat1 = df1, dat2 = df2)
output <- outdat %>%
  full_join(df2, by = c("var1", "var2")) %>% 
  filter((var.start >= (start - 2)) & (var.end <= (end + 2))) %>% 
  select(id, var2, var.start, var.end, var.out) %>%  
  right_join(outdat, by = c("id", "var2", "var.start", "var.end")) %>% 
  arrange(id, var2) 
output <- output[,c(6,1,2,3,4,5)]
output
#>      var1      id var2 var.start var.end var.out
#> 1  task01 id-0023    0       161     228       2
#> 2  task01 id-0023    0       505     526       2
#> 3  task01 id-0023    0       796     820       4
#> 4  task01 id-0023    2         4      55       4
#> 5  task01 id-0023    2       131     200       4
#> 6  task01 id-0023    2       200     269       4
#> 7  task01 id-0023    2       269     389       3
#> 8  task01 id-0023    4       389     539       3
#> 9  task01 id-0023    4       539     555       1
#> 10 task01 id-0023    4       555     632       3
#> 11 task01 id-0023    4       632     782       4
#> 12 task01 id-0023    4       782     941       3
#> 13 task01 id-0150    2       364     389       3
#> 14 task01 id-0150    4       425     470       3
#> 15 task01 id-0150    4       782     941       3
#> 16 task01 id-0181    2       140     176       4
#> 17 task01 id-0181    2       181     200       4
#> 18 task01 id-0181    2       200     269       4
#> 19 task01 id-0181    2       269     391       3
#> 20 task01 id-0181    2       391     481       2
#> 21 task01 id-0181    2       481     482       2
#> 22 task01 id-0181    2       481     482       4
#> 23 task01 id-0181    4       569     631       3
#> 24 task01 id-0181    4       753     782       4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

One difference is that after we split `id-0181`, there is a period from 481-482 which is valid to take 2 different values of `var.out`. In your desired output you don't include a split at this time.

The `right_join()` preserves the order that was in `df2`. So as long as `df2` is sorted as in the example we can simply remove the duplicate row.

```r
nodup <- output[!duplicated(output[,c("var1","id","var2","var.start","var.end")]),]
nodup
#>      var1      id var2 var.start var.end var.out
#> 1  task01 id-0023    0       161     228       2
#> ...
#> 16 task01 id-0181    2       140     176       4
#> 17 task01 id-0181    2       181     200       4
#> 18 task01 id-0181    2       200     269       4
#> 19 task01 id-0181    2       269     391       3
#> 20 task01 id-0181    2       391     481       2
#> 21 task01 id-0181    2       481     482       2
#> 23 task01 id-0181    4       569     631       3
#> 24 task01 id-0181    4       753     782       4
```

This still has an extra split compared to your desired output. This extra time period takes the earliest value of `var.out` it is eligible for. Alternatively we could remove the first duplicate value instead of the second.